# Replication Tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I have created a "Replication" tag.  This tag should be affixed to questions talking about how to replicate a sound found elsewhere.  This is a reasonably common type of question and techniques used for replicating sounds do tend to be similar, but different enough that it will be useful to beginners to be able to look through how to replicate a number of different sounds.

It will also make it easier to identify if a similar sound has been asked about previously.  Additionally, those who prefer to be more design focused and less basics oriented can ignore this tag to avoid seeing such introductory questions if they want.